# Installer for GNAT 2018 community version for x86-64 Mac OS X does not complete

Tags: macos, ada, failed-installation, gnat

The installer runs for a while and many files get installed but it hangs. There is a choice of installing the GNAT compiler tool chain, SPARK tool set and GPS development environment. I've tried it with just the compiler and with all three. Both ways do not complete. Too abort the installer I need to do a force quit.
I have the latest update to MAC OS X installed, plenty of free disk space and memory. I'm trying to install it on MAC Book Pro with touch bar.

Comment: doesn't that install need a `sudo` ? (just an idea)

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre, no, it’s a proper installer. It’ll ask for permission with the usual pop-up if it needs it. I don’t remember whether it did or not. For previous releases, installation was via a shell script, which did need sudo.

Answer (score 3):

I had this issue, and it came up on the [GNAT-OSX mailing list](https://hermes.gwu.edu/cgi-bin/wa?A2=ind1806&L=GNAT-OSX&P=6156), 10 June. (Firefox complains about that site’s security configuration, by the way).

The solution (for Pascal on the list, and for me) was to install **with the 'detailed view' off**.

Comment: I ran into the same problem and it solved itself by installing with the 'detailed view' off, as Simon and Pascal already has written.

Comment: Turning detailed view off did not help for me.